# laravel 5.8 data base query Builder

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, запрос

Есть поле дата формата `Y-m-d` пример заполниной таблицы
ID Date
1 2019-05-19
2 2019-05-30
3 2019-05-22
4 2019-06-03

Нужно сделать выборку чтобы понять какие записи истекают через **месяц**
Например: Если сегодня 2019-05-30 то в выборку должны попасть записи под ID - 1,3, а завтра уже попадут под выборку 1,2,3 как построить правильно запрос ведь например получить даты которые истекают можно

```
$datenow = Carbon::now();  
Date::where('date', '<=', $datenow->addMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
          ->get();
```

Так мы поймет какие записи попадат, по такому запросу попадут все записи. Логично написать было бы

```
->whereNot('date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
          ->get();
```

Но метода

> whereNot

не существует как быть?

Comment: Есть `where('date', 'between', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])` а ещё есть `whereDate('date', 'between', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])`

Answer (score 0):

Так получается вам достаточно выбрать записи дата в которых меньше текущей:

```
$datenow = Carbon::now();  
Date::where('date', '<', $datenow->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Comment: не правильно Вы поняли задачу.

Comment: А если бы автору вопроса нужно было получить записи, которые просрочатся не через месяц, а через год?

Comment: @Domilola, моё условие равноценно вашему:
`->whereNot('date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
          ->get();`

Comment: @РустамГимранов, если мы от текущей даты берём просрочку, то не имеет значения какой будет период этой просрочки.

Comment: Покажите мне данные при которых это условие будет работать не корректно. Предполагаю что задача изначально не верно поставлена.

Comment: @Qraxin почитайте пожалуйста пункт например

Comment: Ясно дело, что не понятно, чего автор хочет добиться. Видимо он хочет метод `->whereNot()`, чтобы не писать `->addMonth()`.